# nodejs cannot run with express

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean, pm2

I installed nodejs and express but it cannot run my Main.js correctly

it shows:
Cannot GET /Main/

/etc/nginx/sites-available/digitalocean:

```
 location /Main/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Main.js:

```
var express = require('express');

console.log('done');
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen('8080', function () {
console.log('Test');
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a running Express server does NOTHING by default.  You have to define routes for each URL that you want to actively serve some content.  So, you have a running server with no routes, therefore it isn't doing anything useful.  You don't even have an error handling route that will at least serve a 404 error for a request for an unsupported route.  You can start by adding that just to see if you're even getting the 404 error or not.  If not, then the first issue is in the nginx configuration.  If so, then you just need to add routes to your express code.

Comment: Also, I'd strong suggest you run a plain express app (without nginx) on your own local computer first.  Get that to work.  Then, if you want to configure it with nginx in front, then work on that configuration while starting with a known working Express app.  Right now you have two unknown systems and probably have problems in both.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the route in my code but it is still not work. However, i have tried to run the code locally and it returns the true result. I guess it is the problem of nginx configuration but how can i find out the problem?

Comment: i get this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" from chrome

Answer (score 3):

You have mapped /Main route to http://localhost:8080, but there are no routes in your express app, hence the request is failing. Your current code just starts up a server, but doesn't serve any content.

Create a default route to view if your endpoint is working.
change Main.js to

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen('8080', function () {
console.log('Test');
});
```

Comment: I have added route to my code but it is still not working in server. I have tried to run the code locally and it returns the true result.

Answer (score 0):

I change the code as follow, then the problem is fixed. It is the problem of route.

Main.js :

```
var express = require('express');

console.log('done');
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.get('/Main', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen('8080', function () {
console.log('Test');
})
```